# C# Webdriver FindsBy - for Kendo elements

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

I am trying to introduce FindsBy  in my test project

```cs
public class BoaRegistrationPage
{
    public IWebDriver Driver;

    public BoaRegistrationPage(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        this.Driver = driver;
        PageFactory.InitElements(driver, this);
    }

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "ReportingPeriodName")]
    public SeleniumKendoDropDownList ReportingPeriodDropDown { get; set; }

    [FindsBy(How=How.Id, Using ="BranchCode")]
    public IWebElement BranchCode { get; set; }
}
```

(...)

Unfortunately as you can see I need to use it also on type other than IWebElement which returns error (SeleniuKendoDropDownList).

```cs
namespace CompanyReviewSeleniumTests.Wrappers
{
    public class SeleniumKendoDropDownList : KendoDropDownList 
    {
        public SeleniumKendoDropDownList(IWebElement webElement) : base(webElement)
        {
            this.CopyInternalId(webElement);
        }

        public void SelectByDataItemProperty(string propertyName, string text)
        {
            Driver.JavaScripts()
                .ExecuteScript(
                    string.Format(
                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                        "$('{0}').data('{1}').select(function(dataItem) {{return dataItem.{3} === '{2}';}});",
                        ElementCssSelector,
                        SelectType,
                        text,
                        propertyName));
        }

        public new void SelectByText(string text)
        {
            WaitUntilOptionsLoaded();
            Open();
            var listBoxElement = Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector($"{this.ElementCssSelector}_listbox"));
            listBoxElement.FindElement(By.XPath($".//*[contains(text(),'{text}')]"))?.JavaScriptClick();
        }
    }
}
```

(...)

How can I manage it?

Thank you in advance for help

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: @gplusplus that FindsBy attribute must be of type IWebElement or IList<IWebElement>

Comment: Its not possiable, there is no way FindBys knows if it is a dropdown or a button, you need to write your own proxy which takes the object identification

Comment: @JyothishwarDeo how to start it?

Comment: @gplusplus Message: System.ArgumentException : Type of member 'SeleniumKendoDropDownList' is not IWebElement or IList<IWebElement>

Answer (score 0):

I can't myself but can you try the following:

```
public class BoaRegistrationPage
{
    public IWebDriver Driver;
    private SeleniumKendoDropDownList _dropDownList;

    public BoaRegistrationPage(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        this.Driver = driver;
        this._dropDownList = null;
        PageFactory.InitElements(driver, this);
    }

    [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "ReportingPeriodName")]
    public IWebElement ReportingPeriodDropDown
    {
        get { return _dropDownList; }
        set { this._dropDownList = new SeleniumKendoDropDownList(value); }
    }

    [FindsBy(How=How.Id, Using ="BranchCode")]
    public IWebElement BranchCode { get; set; }
}
```

Because `KendoDropDownList` inherits from `RemoteWebElement` class which in turn implements `IWebElement` interface, this should work. However, if you need access to SeleniumKendoDropDownList's properties and methods from outside, you'll have to cast, e.g.:

```
((SeleniumKendoDropDownList)boaRegPage.ReportingPeriodDropDown).SelectByDataItemProperty(property, text)
```

Comment: thank you, it helped a little, but now I have a problem as below. When I am trying to use in the test:

((SeleniumKendoDropDownList)page.ReportingPeriodDropDown).SelectByText(RpConstants.2012);

I've got:

Message: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  ----> System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast transparent proxy to type 'OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver'.

Comment: it looks that issue occures even if the part above is commented. I am getting an Exception: : Unable to cast transparent proxy to type 'OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver'.